# CoreAnimation resizing skews UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, resize, core-animation, scale

Disclaimer: I am not an Objective C programmer, but rather collaborate with and manage such a research project, hence my question may be phrased somewhat naively. However, after many discussions with various experts I am assured that this question is relevant so I turn to you as I would greatly appreciate your input.

We need to resize a UIWebView at the Core Animation level. This is a given fact that cannot be altered and which we don't need to discuss here. Just simply resizing the UIWebView itself is not a possibility for this application. Here's the crux:

We load a UIWebView of a certain geometry, let's say 256 x 256 pixel, and then we resize it with Core Animation. Let's say the new target size will be 1024 x 512 pixel. We manage to easily make the UIWebView fit nicely into the new 512 wide space. The problem, however, is that it keeps it's original proportions so that the new UIWebView now covers only half of the target area, i.e. 512 x 512 pixel. This is not unexpected, however, we need the UIWebView to reveal more of its content after such a transform, i.e. to become longer, as to fill the space. We're pretty stuck as we don't really have any other alternative. Once you start thinking about this problem and trying various scenarios you'll find that this is not trivial. If you have any ideas as to how we could resolve / work-around this problem, that would be great!

Let me know - All the best,

Michael

Comment: It would help if you mention what you have tried. Anyway, try my answer. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[webView.scrollView setZoomScale:1f]` after resizing.